# Material UI - React - Place Grid items in a column

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need some help with positioning my Grid Items while using Material UI.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-tgef7) is where I am so far (roughly).

And my question is quite simple - how do I get 2 & 3 to go to the right of 1? I kinda do it but there are all those weird spaces to the left and down that, I cannot figure out how to deal with.

That's the end result I'm after:
[image]

Thank you.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    // display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(12, 1fr)",
    gridGap: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  w: {
    height: "100px"
  },
  divider: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 0)
  }
}));

export default function CSSGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Grid item xs={8}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper + " " + classes.w}>xs=8</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          container
          style={{ display: "table", height: "100%" }}
          direction="row"
        >
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=4</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=4</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Divider className={classes.divider} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notice points from your code

- use one container for one grid field structure
- remove direction setting `direction="column"`
- `xs` sum needs to lower or equal to 12 if you want to set them in one row.

Kindly check the [material-ui grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) document for better understanding

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs={8}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper + " " + classes.w}>xs=8</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=2</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=2</Paper>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
<Divider className={classes.divider} />
```

[image]

---

#### Update:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs={8}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper + " " + classes.w}>xs=8</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=4</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=4</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
<Divider className={classes.divider} />
```

[image]

Try it online:

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Thank you so much, but perhaps I should've been more clear with my explanation. Please excuse me and refer to the edited post. Thank you, once more. :)